# Android vs. iOS Notifications w/ Firebase

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The issue is, iOS notifications only work properly (when app is active, inactive and terminated) if one sets the `notification` field (empty or not). However for Android, one is required to **not** set the `notification` field and only the `data` field (otherwise if the app is inactive or terminated the notifications are automatically handled by the system and one can't manipulate them as in download a picture etc.).

How can i display notifications for both in a way that they appear on all states (active, inactive and terminated) and i can manipulate them before the will be displayed ?

I manipulate the notifications with these methods:

```
// Android
onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage)

// iOS
didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 2):

Save and check the device type (android/ios) of the token before sending your request to Firebase from your backend. Compose body of the request accordingly. e.g. with `notification` field for the iOS tokens, and with `data` field for the Android tokens.

Comment: That is my fallback plan, but there must be some other way than to store the platform and check it before any notification ?